# Failing to open port 10000

Tags: linux, tcp, port, iptables

I need to open port 10000 on my RHEL ver 5.9  server.

What I have done to  open it:

1. Stopped iptables service: 
    `# service iptable stop`
2. Of course from root user executed this command:  
    `# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT`
3. `#  iptables-save   >  /etc/sysconfig/iptables`
4. `#  service iptables start`

Verified  using  iptables -L command:
`#  iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:10000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I am able to telnet on that port from this RHEL server to my windows server 2012.  But I am not able to telnet from windows server.

I thought it is the problem from Linux firewall not windows firewall because I did the same steps on "linux server (test server)" and was able to telnet it after doing the same steps mentioned above.

The error I am getting when telnetting from windows server is :

from windows : 
`telnet <ip_address_of_targeted_linux_server>   10000`

output:
`connecting to <ip_address_of_targeted_linux_server> ... could not open connection to the host, on port 10000: connect failed`

Any idea what I have missed based on the information I gave?

Answer (score 0):

This is to inform you that I have found the solution to my problem.  in /etc/services , ndmp value wasn't 10000.  So I have edited it with the correct value, then  restarted the service that uses that port and was able to connect.